# How do I read Micronaut array properties from the root of the configuration hierarchy?

Tags: java, micronaut

If I have a config file

```
app:
    integers:
        - 1
        - 2
```

I can use Micronaut's ConfigurationProperties to create config beans:

```
@ConfigurationProperties("app")
public class AppConfig {
  public List<Integer> integers;
}
```

But what if the integers array is in the root of the config hierarchy:

```
integers:
    - 1
    - 2
```

The following does not seem to work:

```
@ConfigurationProperties("")
public class RootConfig {
  public List<Integer> integers;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@ConfigurationProperties` only works with a prefix. And `""` is not a valid prefix.

Moreover `@ConfigurationProperties` makes sense only if you have many fields(May be that is why it was not designed to work) not for one field like

```
integers:
    - 1
    - 2
```

In this case `@ConfigurationProperties` is a overkill. Just use `@Value` like this

```
@Value("${integers}")
public List<Integer> integers;
```

and declare it like this in yaml

```
integers: 1,2
```

Comment: And how would you do it, if you did NOT have an array of plain integers but an array of more complex properties? e.g. an array of addresses consisting of street name, area code etc?

Comment: if you have a more complex properties like address, you would create a pojo  and `@ConfigurationProperties` would work just fine

Comment: sorry, but I still do not understand how I could use @ConfigurationProperties with an array like this: "addresses": [ {"street":  "mystreet", "number": 1}, {"street":  "yourstreet", "number": 2} ] ? What prefix would I use?

Comment: I got it. In such cases, you would have to read the yaml  using `YamlPropertySourceLoader ` and create a Pojo yourself. `@ConfigurationProperties` cannot do it. But it is not worth the hassle when you could just add a prefix which would not change any application logic

Comment: "Moreover @ConfigurationProperties works only if you have many fields" - I don't think that is correct.

Comment: I meant it makes sense only when you have multiple fields. Not with single field.... Wrong choice of words.